# Sobrecarga de operadores y su localización en el código

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

tengo una duda que es un poco de perogrullo, pero me gustaría confirmar lo que pienso o aclararlo.

Cuando estas definiendo un tipo y realizas una sobrecarga de operadores para dicho tipo algunos son definidos dentro de la clase y otros fuera. Tengo entendido que eso es así porque algunos necesitan acceso a la representación de la clase, o sea, sus atributos miembro o datos miembro, y otros no, asi que los que no necesitan ese acceso, porque no hacen uso directo de esos atributos se definen fuera.

Ejemplo:

```
class complex{
double real, imaginario;

public:
complex():real{0}, imaginario{0};

//getters&setters

complex& operator+=(complex z){
    real+=z.real, imaginario+=z.imaginario;
    return *this;}
};

complex operator+(complex a, complex b) {return a+=b;}
```

Entonces, yo puedo situar, por ejemplo, la sobrecarga del operador + en otro archivo de código fuente, ¿no? Y el compilador sabe que me refiero a ese tipo, ¿por el tipo que devuelve? Asume el contexto.

Y, ¿cuando defino el operador +, el += aritmético que utiliza ya es el que he definido anteriormente?¿Importa el orden?¿Si utilizo un operador no sobrecargado, usaría el del tipo double?

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo entendido que eso es así porque algunos necesitan acceso a la representación de la clase, o sea, sus atributos miembro o datos miembro, y otros no, asi que los que no necesitan ese acceso, porque no hacen uso directo de esos atributos se definen fuera.

Eso no es del todo cierto. La única diferencia, en términos generales, la diferencia más significativa entre un operador declarado como miembro y otro declarado como función libre es que el operador miembro tiene a su disposición el puntero `this`. Este puntero, por supuesto, le permite acceder a todas las variables del objeto sin restricciones... pero también es cierto que una función libre puede ser `friend` de la clase... lo que asigna el mismo nivel de acceso.

Como norma general es deseable que los operadores no sean funciones miembro, por varias razones:

- Reduce el acoplamiento: Si usas operadores binarios (dos parámetros) cuyos parámetros son de diferente tipo, estarás añadiendo dependencias a nivel de la clase que probablemente no necesites (esto complica el diseño del código y hace que tarde más en compilar). Mantener los operadores como funciones libres te permite cargarlos únicamente allí donde se usan de forma efectiva.
- Mejora el encapsulamiento: Los operadores raramente necesitan acceder sí o sí a las variables privadas para poder ser implementados. Obligar a que su implementación haga uso de la interfaz pública del objeto es una garantía de seguridad.
- Operadores más versátiles: Los operadores binarios con parámetros de diferente tipo necesitan implementarse dos veces para tener un comportamiento simétrico.

  ```
  class A;
  class B;

  A operator+(A const& a, B const& b);
  B operator+(B const& b, A const& a);
  ```

  Implementar estos operadores como funciones libres te permite tener los dos operadores juntos, mientras que si son miembros tendrás que poner cada operador en una clase diferente.

  ```
  class B;

  class A
  {
  public:
    A operator+(B const& b);
  };

  class B
  {
  public:
    B operator+(A const& a);
  };
  ```

  Si además resulta que uno de los tipos es nativo (`int` por ejemplo) una de las implementaciones deberá ser obligatoriamente una función libre

  ```
  // Asimetrico
  class A
  {
    A operator+(int); // A a; a = a + 5
  };

  A operator+(int, A const&); // A a; a = 5 + a

  // Simetrico
  class A;

  A operator+(A const&, int);
  A operator+(int, A const&);
  ```

> Entonces, yo puedo situar, por ejemplo, la sobrecarga del operador + en otro archivo de código fuente, ¿no? Y el compilador sabe que me refiero a ese tipo, ¿por el tipo que devuelve? Asume el contexto

El compilador no asume absolutamente nada, ya que asumir implica que no tienes toda la información disponible... y cuando al compilador le falta información finaliza el montaje con un error y se queda tan pancho.

Si implementas una sobrecarga como una función libre podrás poner la declaración y la implementación donde te de la gana. Eso sí, para poder usar esa sobrecarga tendrás que *incluir* la declaración antes de su uso. Si se te olvida ese *pequeño* detalle el compilador puede actuar de dos maneras posibles:

- No encuentra una sobrecarga adecuada y finaliza con error
- Descubre que puede hacer una conversión implícita y aplica un operador que no esperas.

Lo deseable es que siempre sucediese lo primero, ya que el segundo caso genera errores en tiempo de ejecución bastante desconcertantes.

Un pequeño ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
struct datos
{
};

void func1()
{
  datos d1;
  std::cout << d1; // <<--- ERROR: No se encuentra la sobrecarga
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, datos d)
{
  os << "operador de insercion\n";
  return os;
}

void func2()
{
  datos d1;
  std::cout << d1; // <<--- OK
}
```

Como puedes ver, el compilador no asume absolutamente nada... bueno sí, asume que tu debes resolver todas sus dudas.

> Y, ¿cuando defino el operador +, el += aritmético que utiliza ya es el que he definido anteriormente?

Son operadores diferentes que deben declararse por separado. Si declaras el operador `+` y no declaras el operador `+=` no podrás usar el operador `+=`, como es obvio.

> ¿Importa el orden?

En absoluto. Son funciones totalmente independientes y libres.

> ¿Si utilizo un operador no sobrecargado, usaría el del tipo double?

Los operadores se comportan como funciones. De hecho puedes invocar al operador como si de una función se tratase:

```
complex a, b;
complex c = operator+(a,b);
```

Así que el operador *no usa* un tipo, sino que intenta llamar a la función que actúa como un operador. A la hora de decidir a qué función llama aplica las mismas que en el caso de funciones *normales*. Es decir:

1. Busca un operador directo (no requiere conversiones)
2. Busca un operador indirecto (requiere conversiones implícitas)
3. Error

Answer (score 0):

Cuando empiezas a realizar un código y poco a poco lo vas agrandando, llegará un momento en el que tendrás que conocer el concepto de "separación" para que no esté todo dentro de main.cpp.

Ese momento ha llegado para ti.

> Entonces, yo puedo situar, por ejemplo, la sobrecarga del operador + en otro archivo de código fuente, ¿no? Y el compilador sabe que me refiero a ese tipo, ¿por el tipo que devuelve? Asume el contexto.

De hecho, lo normal es que sitúes la implementación o definición del código (qué hace) en un archivo y la declaración del código (cómo tienes que llamarlo o declararlo) en otro archivo.

La nomenclatura general es que los archivos `.h` contengan la declaración  y los archivos `.cpp` tengan la definición.

Una vez tengas esto claro, vamos al siguiente punto: **¿El compilador sabe qué tipo es al que te refieres?** De hecho, ese es su trabajo, saberlo.

Cuando tú haces esto:

```
a + b
```

Debes haber definido anteriormente qué es `a` y qué es `b`. Una vez sepa el compilador qué son ambas, buscará en tu código fuente, en el suyo y en todas partes donde le hayas dicho que puede buscar, si existe la función `operator +( *tipo_a*, *tipo_b* )`. Si no la encuentra, te pegará un petardazo. De hecho, no puedes dedirle a ese `operator` que devuelva ningún tipo sobrecargado, sólo devolverá un único tipo.

Para llamarlo desde un archivo, primero, en el `.h`, deberás introducir la declaración pelada y mondada, sin llaves, utilizando un `;` al final:

```
class complex
{
  private:
  double re, im;

  public:
  complex():re{0}, im{0};

  complex& operator+=(complex z);
};
```

Después, en tu `.cpp`, pondrás tu código para que, cuando se compile, sepa qué tiene que hacer:

```
complex& complex::operator+=(complex z)
{
  this->re += z.re;
  this->im += z.im;
  return *this;
}
```

Y prepara tu compilador para que compile el archivo .cpp, claro está.
Me he permitido el lujo de limpiarte y ponerte más legible el código. Recuérdalo para futuras referencias, tu código lo leemos otros.

El puntero `this->` te ayudará con IDEs modernos para saltarte la detección de métodos. De hecho, este código no funcionará porque `re` e `im` son privados, y necesitarás un `accesor` a estos elementos.

Creo que esta pequeña introducción a la separación puede serte de ayuda.